# Error: Mutex to check, if the application is already running

Tags: c#, xaml, mutex, show

Hey guys I've got the following problem: I declared the mutex to check, if the application is already running. If a file I need in my project is missing, there is an error message and a method, that CLOSES the application before the InitializeComponent(). Everytime a file is missing, I get an error due to the following line:

```
W.Show();
```

Here is, what I've got so far:

```
Startup="Application_Startup">

public void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        bool Absicherung;
        Mutex Mutex = new Mutex(true, this.GetType().GUID.ToString(), out Absicherung);

        if (Absicherung)
        {
            Window W = new MainWindow();
            W.Closed += (sender2, args) => Mutex.Close(); ;
            W.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Die Anwendung läuft bereits. Eine mehrfache Ausführung dieser ist nicht vorgesehen.", "Hinweis: Anwendung läuft bereits", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            Mutex.Close();
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this problem? Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Problem fixed.** Solution: Closing the application with this.Close() is the wrong way - it works using Application.Current.Shutdown(); --> ~closed.

Comment: Problem fixed. Solution: Closing the application with this.Close() is the wrong way - it works using Application.Current.Shutdown(); --> ~closed.

Comment: Can you post the solution as an Answer instead of incorporating it into the Question.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not allowed to do that: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 1/31/2014 10:49:02 PM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead." - but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Oh, I see. I keep forgetting these things :)